# Change uitextfield using the dismiss keyboard icon on the iPad

Tags: ipad

On the iPad there is an icon to dismiss the keyboard on the bottom right of the screen. When a user changes their input data, and taps on this icon, the prior results (calculations) are still displayed. I need to change the UITextField results so that they know they must tap on my submit button to update the results. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is looking for the [`UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uikeyboardwillhidenotification), you'll know when you can update your calculations.

[Sample code can be seen here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462-Classes_ViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6).

p.s. welcome to StackOverflow! For future questions, it might be useful to tag then with the language that you're using ([objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) or [swift](/questions/tagged/swift)), as well as [ios](/questions/tagged/ios).